# HTTP Error 400 Syntax Error

Tags: python, api, yelp

This code is supposed to use the Yelp API to retrieve information about restaurants. Every time I run it, I get a HTTP 400 Error, which I think should mean a syntax error. In reviewing it by myself I cannot find my error. I've searched Stack Overflow for a question related to mine and haven't found one.

The return Error message is: `Encountered HTTP error 400. Abort program.`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Yelp API v2.0 code sample.

This program demonstrates the capability of the Yelp API version 2.0
by using the Search API to query for businesses by a search term and location,
and the Business API to query additional information about the top result
from the search query.

Please refer to http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation for the API documentation.

This program requires the Python oauth2 library, which you can install via:
`pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Sample usage of the program:
`python sample.py --term="bars" --location="San Francisco, CA"`
"""
import argparse
import json
import pprint
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import oauth2

API_HOST = 'api.yelp.com'
DEFAULT_TERM = 'restaurants'
DEFAULT_LOCATION = 'Ottawa'
SEARCH_LIMIT = '75'
SEARCH_PATH = '/v2/search/'
BUSINESS_PATH = '/v2/business/'

# OAuth credential placeholders that must be filled in by users.
CONSUMER_KEY =########
CONSUMER_SECRET =######
TOKEN =#######
TOKEN_SECRET =#######

def request(host, path, url_params=None):
    """Prepares OAuth authentication and sends the request to the API.

    Args:
        host (str): The domain host of the API.
        path (str): The path of the API after the domain.
        url_params (dict): An optional set of query parameters in the request.

    Returns:
        dict: The JSON response from the request.

    Raises:
        urllib2.HTTPError: An error occurs from the HTTP request.
    """
    url_params = url_params or {}
    encoded_params = urllib.urlencode(url_params)

    url = 'http://{0}{1}?{2}'.format(host, path, encoded_params)

    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    oauth_request = oauth2.Request('GET', url, {})
    oauth_request.update(
        {
            'oauth_nonce': oauth2.generate_nonce(),
            'oauth_timestamp': oauth2.generate_timestamp(),
            'oauth_token': TOKEN,
            'oauth_consumer_key': CONSUMER_KEY
        }
    )
    token = oauth2.Token(TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET)
    oauth_request.sign_request(oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), consumer, token)
    signed_url = oauth_request.to_url()

    print 'Querying {0} ...'.format(url)

    conn = urllib2.urlopen(signed_url, None)
    try:
        response = json.loads(conn.read())
    finally:
        conn.close()

    return response

def search(term, location):
    """Query the Search API by a search term and location.

    Args:
        term (str): The search term passed to the API.
        location (str): The search location passed to the API.

    Returns:
        dict: The JSON response from the request.
    """
    url_params = {
        'term': term,
        'location': location,
        'limit': SEARCH_LIMIT
    }

    return request(API_HOST, SEARCH_PATH, url_params=url_params)

def get_business(business_id):
    """Query the Business API by a business ID.

    Args:
        business_id (str): The ID of the business to query.

    Returns:
        dict: The JSON response from the request.
    """
    business_path = BUSINESS_PATH + business_id

    return request(API_HOST, business_path)

def query_api(term, location):
    """Queries the API by the input values from the user.

    Args:
        term (str): The search term to query.
        location (str): The location of the business to query.
    """
    response = search(term, location)

    businesses = response.get('businesses')

    if not businesses:
        print 'No businesses for {0} in {1} found.'.format(term, location)
        return

    business_id = businesses[0]['id']

    print '{0} businesses found, querying business info for the top result "{1}" ...'.format(
        len(businesses),
        business_id
    )

    response = get_business(business_id)

    print 'Result for business "{0}" found:'.format(business_id)
    pprint.pprint(response, indent=2)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-q', '--term', dest='term', default=DEFAULT_TERM, type=str, help='Search term (default: %(default)s)')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', dest='location', default=DEFAULT_LOCATION, type=str, help='Search location (default: %(default)s)')

input_values = parser.parse_args()

try:
    query_api(input_values.term, input_values.location)
except urllib2.HTTPError as error:
    sys.exit('Encountered HTTP error {0}. Abort program.'.format(error.code))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you're a new programmer then you should learn the basics of programming instead of copying more advanced programs and wondering why they don't work.  - And look at the help center about how to ask a good question.

Comment: You didn't even add full error message in question, and you didn't describe what that script is doing (or should do).

Comment: As for me - script send some request to server (some `url`) and server can't recognize that `url`. You could try to use that url in web browser and see what happens.

Comment: In yelp api v2 they use oauth 1.oa,but use oauth2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You limit parameter is set to a very high value. try something like 10 to begin with.

Comment: That is exactly what i tried and it worked you have a limit of 25 per search.

Comment: I am getting the same error. It works for the first 9 requests and then always fails on the 10th? and my limit is only 20

Answer (score 1):

In yelp api v2 they use [oauth 1.oa](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor12),but you use oauth2.